# How to maximise a window within a Windows remote desktop session

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm logged in to a Windows 7 machine from a Windows 7 desktop, using the standard Remote Desktop client.

Is there a key short cut to maximise a window within the remote desktop session (equivalent to Windows+up arrow)?

I want the remote desktop session to NOT be full screen on my client machine, but to easily maximise windows on the remote session to the full size of the remote desktop window.

Hope that makes sense. ;)

Comment: Have you tried clicking the maximise button on the window's title bar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> in the Remote Desktop session opens the Windows menu of an application running on the remote system. The Windows menu is typically displayed under the icon in the extreme upper left corner of most Windows applications, and it lets you Maximize the application window.

You may use the following combos for sizing the window:

Maximize: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>

Minimize: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>

Restore:  <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>

Resize: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>

Comment: That's great, thanks. :) I'd forgotten about this menu, I think I used it  in the days before Windows 7. It's a two-step short cut but I suspect that's as good as it gets.

Comment: @user68234 You may also alter the behavior of RDP. Under "Options", "Local Resources", "Apply Windows key combinations" you may opt for on of "On this computer", "On remote computer", "Only when using full screen". Selecting "On remote computer" will pass-through the keys as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Go to start. Click on Remote Desktop Connection. That opens the Remote Connection Window. It has a drop down at the bottom called Options. Click on Options. That opens up a tabbed options screen. Go to Display tab. In the DIsplay configuration section drag the slider to the right to full screen. Click Connect. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, I often work full screen as you describe and there's no issue there. Other times, I want to work in a smaller window, for example if I'm often switching between local and remote, and then the Remote Desktop-specific shortcuts are in use. My question was about those shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

click on the options button and then

in the Local Resource Tab , in Keyboard section ,Apply windows key combination helps you to go back to your windows

[image: restore to host desktop]

Comment: That's not an answer to the question - he's asking if it's possible to/what the shortcut key combo is to maximize an application within the RDP session, not how to maximize the RDP window itself.

Comment: Indeed, it's not quite what I was looking for, but thanks for going to the trouble with the screen grab.

Answer (score -1):

nope you can't its defined size of width by remote sharing.. Also I would like you to try it by changing its resolutions may that could make it full screen for you

Answer (score -2):

try Ctrl+Alt+pause/break works for me
if you haven't got pause/break try ctrl+alt+fn+F6 or f12

Comment: It's a wrong answer.  Ctrl + Alt + Pause/Break is the keyboard shortcut for toggling an RDP session window between full screen mode and windowed mode.